# Do not show chat flags outside of large rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add escalation system to chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112756/add-escalation-system-to-chat-flags)

To cut down on network-wide flag spam, flags that occur in "sufficiently large" rooms (with X blues and/or Y 10k's) should not be shown to all 10k's in all rooms.  If the flag is not resolved/stalemates after Z minutes, it could then bug everybody.

This would both prevent other users from being bothered as well as leave the moderation to members of the room to address, who are presumably better aware of the context, if not the culture of the room itself.

Comment: The chat rooms may be hidden but should not be moderated as such. Rules are rules.

Comment: @M.Babcock so users in said rooms are unable to moderate themselves?  Even if the room had X blues (mods) who are presumably well-versed in site policy, they unable to moderate without external assistance?