# What is the tipping point for making the PTB care about feature requests?

Tags: discussion

[Add escalation system to chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112756/add-escalation-system-to-chat-flags)

The post in the link has 93 upvotes with an impressive first answer of 38 upvotes. Neither has a *single* downvote. It seems to overwhemingly indicate that the community is strongly in favour of the request. Also, in about 7 days, it is possible that the top answer may be loaded with 1700 rep from bounties.

Are there triggers that would make the PTB look at feature requests seriously? Such as 100 upvotes on question? On answer? 5 bounties awarded? 2000 rep from bounties?  What more can the community do to *encourage* a feature request along?

Comment: There is no defined tipping point. You can't do much more than support it. There are no guarantees.

Comment: Would that change if I donated BitCoins in the truckloads to the TPB, or scrimp a little and give fewer BitCoins to just one specific person?

Comment: By all means donate to me and we should have this sorted in 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't an explicit cut-off point that *guarantees* that something will be implemented.

At the end of the day, we still have to wrestle with sorting out a bunch of priorities. There is a lot of work being done on several different projects. It's not like we have a team of developers sitting idle and waiting for that next community-backed feature request to come along. :)

There is also a chance that even though a request is really popular, it's not something we're interested in implementing at all. Those we do try to respond to with an explicit [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), though.

Far as that specific request goes, we know it's something the community is fairly passionate about. I'm personally on board with some sort of an escalation system for chat flags. However, right now, there's just too much other, more pressing stuff going on for anyone to champion that feature internally and see it through. It hasn't been declined. We'll try to get to it or something similar. (No promises on the exact implementation if/when we do look at it.)

Comment: Maybe, then, the tag [meta-tag:status-deferred] should be used more often? It would be nice to know that these requests are thought about and considered seriously.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Probably. Although I wouldn't say that this is being actively thought about by anybody. You can usually think of any request that hasn't been explicitly declined as deferred. Sometimes things pick up support later on too, so we generally tend to leave feature requests alone.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there [additional] triggers that would make the PTB look at feature requests seriously?

No.  There really isn't anything else for the community to do.

At some point you need to keep in mind that certain decisions are made by the community and certain decisions aren't.  What features should be implemented doesn't fall into the category of decisions made by the community.